# Use JOIN in SQL query instead of subquery

Tags: sql, mysql, join, subquery, query-optimization

I have a SQL query which works but is slow. I wondered if there is a more efficient way to express it using joins.

**Scenario**:

Tables: `productions`, `scripts` and a join table, `productions_scripts`

| productions |
| --- |
| id (int) |
| production (text) |

| scripts |
| --- |
| id (int) |
| script (text) |
| canonical (bool) |

| productions_scripts |
| --- |
| id (int) |
| production_id (int) |
| script_id (int) |

**Requirement**:

Return a listing of productions and their associated scripts where the production has more than one script of type 'canonical'. Only show results where the script is canonical.

**Current query**:

```
SELECT productions.id AS production_id, productions.production,
       scripts.id AS script_id, scripts.script
FROM scripts, productions, productions_scripts
WHERE productions.id IN (SELECT productions_scripts.production_id
                         FROM productions_scripts, scripts
                         WHERE scripts.id = productions_scripts.script_id
                           AND scripts.canonical = 1
                         GROUP BY production_id
                         HAVING COUNT(production_id) > 1
                         )
AND productions.id = productions_scripts.production_id
AND scripts.id = productions_scripts.script_id
AND scripts.canonical = 1
ORDER BY production_id;
```

**Issues**:
The query works but takes a long time to run. (~45 secs.)

The main difficulty I encountered in writing the query was getting a count of productions with multiple canonical scripts, while having the requirement to output a row for every matching production-script combination rather than just unique values for `production_id`.

It seems that I have to use `GROUP BY production_id` to get the count. But this also results in the output of unique values for `production_id`. Hence the subquery.

EDIT.
The query I posted was the wrong version - it returned productions with non-canonical scripts. I have updated it with the `AND scripts.canonical = 1` clause in the final section.

Comment: Add table and index definitions, and the explain output.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: How long is _"a long time"_? Make sure your junction table (`productions_scripts`) is indexed with composite keys in both directions, ideally with one of them as the PK instead of your surrogate.

Comment: You fixed the query, but not the requirement.

Comment: I had a go at updating the requirement.

Comment: Side note: `productions_scripts` does not need a separate `id` column, it should only have a composite primary key `(production_id, script_id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using multiple `INNER JOIN` clauses :

```
SELECT p.id AS production_id, p.production, s.id AS script_id, s.script
FROM productions p 
INNER JOIN productions_scripts ps ON p.id = ps.production_id
INNER JOIN scripts s ON s.id = ps.script_id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ps.production_id
  FROM productions_scripts ps
  INNER JOIN scripts s ON s.id = ps.script_id
  WHERE s.canonical = 1
  GROUP BY ps.production_id
  HAVING COUNT(ps.production_id) > 1
) AS t ON t.production_id = p.id
WHERE s.canonical = 1
ORDER BY p.id;
```

Comment: I take it that the penultimate line should read: 
`AS t ON t.production_id = p.id`
This query completes very quickly but as with my original query (see edit above) it returns rows of productions with non-canonical scripts.

Comment: Can you check my recent edit

Comment: It's missing the requirement to have more than one canonical script associated with the production.

Comment: Looking good, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function instead of the subquery.

```sql
SELECT
  p.production_id,
  p.production,
  p.script_id,
  p.script
FROM (
    SELECT
      p.id AS production_id,
      p.production,
      s.id AS script_id,
      s.script,
      COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY p.id) AS countCanonical
    FROM scripts s
    JOIN productions_scripts ps
      ON s.id = ps.script_id
    JOIN productions p
      ON p.id = ps.production_id
    WHERE s.canonical = 1
) p
WHERE p.countCanonical > 1
ORDER BY production_id;
```

Note that you should use explicit join syntax, rather than comma=joins.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I get syntax errors for symbol 's' in lines 4 and 5. It seems the definition of `scripts s` should be relocated. (There are a couple of other small typos which I fixed)

Comment: Sorry fixed now

Comment: I couldn't get it to run, there is an issue with the `PARTITION BY` part, I think maybe you meant `p.id`? But an error is thrown at that line even when updated.

Comment: Fixed. What error now?

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY p.id) AS countCanonical FROM scripts s ' at line 12`

Comment: Do you have MySQL version 8+ this is the only supported version these days.

Comment: No it's a legacy database I'm going to update, v5.5.x.
I will look into your approach on the new installation.

Answer (score 0):

Having appropriate indexes will definitely help and as basic as these tables are, I would just show and you can confirm

```
Table               Index
production          (id, production)
script              (id, canonical, script)
productions_scripts ( production_id, script_id )
```

Next, your sub-query was on target, but as other person noted, use explicit joins vs comma list of tables.

Lastly, as this is from MySQL, I would through in the keyword "STRAIGHT_JOIN" which tells MySql to do the query in the order I have listed, dont think for me.  I dont know your data table sizes (records), but from a system I worked with years ago with 20+ million records linked to 25+ lookup tables for corresponding descriptions, that one keyword took a query from crashing the server to having it return result in less than 2 hours.

Having said that, I would revise to:

```
select STRAIGHT_JOIN
        p.id production_id,
        p.production,
        s.id script_id,
        s.script,
        s.canonical
    from
        (SELECT 
                ps.production_id
            FROM 
                productions_scripts ps
                    JOIN scripts s
                        on ps.script_id = s.id
                        AND s.canonical = 1
            group by
                ps.production_id
            having
                count(*) > 1 ) multi
            JOIN production_scripts ps2
                on multi.production_id = ps2.production_id
                JOIN production p
                    on ps2.production_id = p.id
                JOIN scripts s
                    on ps2.script_id = s.id
    order by
        multi.production_id
```

The inner query relies on itself joined to the scripts for canonical only having the count of any record matching qualified > 1.  Then, immediately take that production ID qualified to re-join to the rest of the tables to pull the respective details.

Comment: Thanks for the useful suggestions. You are correct about the indexes which exist on these tables.
Your query completes very quickly but as with my original query (see my edit above) it returns rows of productions with non-canonical scripts

Comment: Actually the script table only has an index on id. Otherwise they match your schema above.

Comment: It works fine if I add a WHERE clause before the last ORDER BY:
`WHERE s.canonical = 1`
And it completes slightly more quickly than @SeVazi's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MySQL ≥ 8.0 (but doubtful given your struggles with [Charlieface's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77660434/use-join-in-sql-query-instead-of-subquery#77660570)), and `p.production` and `s.script` are both sizeable text fields, you *may* benefit from a hybrid of the approaches shown by SelVazi and Charlieface:

```sql
SELECT
  p.id AS production_id,
  p.production,
  s.id AS script_id,
  s.script
FROM (
    SELECT
      ps.*,
      COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ps.production_id) AS countCanonical
    FROM scripts s
    JOIN productions_scripts ps
      ON s.id = ps.script_id
    WHERE s.canonical = 1
) m
JOIN scripts s
  ON m.script_id = s.id
JOIN productions p
  ON m.production_id = p.id
WHERE m.countCanonical > 1
ORDER BY p.id;
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a legacy database I'm going to update, v5.5.x. I will look into your approach on the new installation.

Comment: @Charlieface With an index on `canonical`, the temp table for the window function can be materialised without including either of the `text` columns, keeping it much smaller and faster. Then it is simple PK based joins to retrieve the `text` columns only for the rows that OP is interested in. Obviously, whether this approach is beneficial is dependent on how selective the subquery is and the size of the `text` columns.

Comment: @Charlieface - [Derived table merging for a subquery is disabled if the subquery has window functions. The subquery is always materialized.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.2/en/window-function-optimization.html#:~:text=Derived%20table%20merging%20for%20a%20subquery%20is%20disabled%20if%20the%20subquery%20has%20window%20functions.%20The%20subquery%20is%20always%20materialized.)

Comment: Ah forgot MySQL is a toy database